# add scrollpane to panel which has another panel in it

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollbar

I have a panel `drawSomething` to draw something in it and I need its size to be big and I have another `panel` in my frame to put that panel `drawSomething` in it so, I need to put `scrollpane` around panel how can I do it?

here is my sample code :

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;


public class myFrame extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myFrame mf = new myFrame();
        mf.setSize(400,400);
        mf.setVisible(true);
        mf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mf.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        JPanel drawSomething = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 200);
        drawSomething.setSize(500, 500);
        drawSomething.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        panel1.add(drawSomething);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel1);
        mf.add(scroll);

    }
}
```

Comment: panel1.add(new JScrollPane(drawSomething)); ?

Comment: `null` layouts will not help

Comment: Start by choosing a layout, `mf.setLayout(null);` is the first thing to fix. Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html using LayoutManager and fix this. Next up, consider using Java standard class names http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367 `MyFrame` rather than `myFrame`. Once you have a Layout set, then start to add the components one by one as you want them.

Comment: Also, you didn't even need to extend your class to JFrame in this case. I think it would be best to just initialize your frame as an instance of JFrame directly since you're not really adding anything to the subclass 'myFrame'.

Comment: ad difference is between description and code posted here